# Casting a vector address to copy data

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have written an operation that seems to work fine, but I can't tell if it is really .. legal.

I have a row class, and extension

```
class Row {};
class SuperRow : public Row {};
```

I have a function that returns a vector

```
std::vector<Row> GetRows(){
    Row row1;
    Row row2;
    std::vector<Row> rows;
    rows.push_back(row1);
    rows.push_back(row2);
    return rows;
}
```

I have another function that wants that data, but it has a vector of objects that extend the main vector's data type.

```
void GetData(std::vector<SuperRow> *rows){
    // in order to compile, must do this
    *((std::vector<Row>*)rows) = GetRows();
}
```

This works, but I'm looking at it like I'm doing something wrong..
[edit: OK, clearly this is terrible]

---

I am also doing maybe the same thing in a different way..

```
void GetRowsOtherWay(std::vector<Row> *rows){
   *rows = GetRows();
}

void GetDataOtherWay(std::vector<SuperRow> *rows){
    GetRowsOtherWay((std::vector<Row>*)rows);
}
```

Is this also bad?

Comment: AFAIK this is nasal demons

Comment: @SombreroChicken but you don't even have a nose! UB sure is scary.

Comment: Contains UB and slicing.

Comment: @Quentin Your UB is the equivalent of oral leeks. Flying. Everywhere.

Comment: `std::vector<T>` and `std::vector<U>` are unrelated, regardless of the relationship between `T` and `U` (unless `T` and `U` are exactly the same type). You need to copy the vector element-wise (one element at a time).

Comment: In general if you are using a cast, especially a C style cast in C++ the likelihood that you are doing something ill advised or just plain wrong is fairly high. You can often use a C style cast in order to make something compile but just because it compiles does not mean it is right. UB by the way is Undefined Behavior which means that the code is written such that there is no clear, unambiguous functionality that may come from the code. It might work or it might not.

Comment: What`s wrong in just returning the vector "by value"? It would copy the header structure with the pointer to the actual data.

Comment: *I have another function that wants that data, but it has a vector of objects that extend the main vector's data type.* -- There is a reason why [std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) exists, and your case is one of them.

Comment: This may appear to work (even though it's undefined behavior) in this exact code, but as soon as `Row` and `SuperRow` get more complicated you will probably observe nasty things happening. And your "other way" is exactly the same as the first one - you cannot convert a pointer to `std::vector<X>` to a pointer to `std::vector<Y>` if `X` and `Y` are different.

Comment: Side note: Why do you have pointers to the `vector`s? You are not even checking if they are `nullptr` before dereferencing them. You should probably use references.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I wrote this all as an example to illustrate the real question

Comment: Is this just "not okay" with containers? Because everywhere in our code base I see people casting object ptrs to their base classes, ie `GetThatRow((Row*)&mySuperRow);`

Comment: @errno_44 Ok, I'd change it to references in the question to not obscure the real question.

Comment: @errno_44 `GetRowsOtherWay((std::vector<Row>*)rows);` -- Remove those C-style cast from your code and recompile your program.  What error does the compiler give you?  Whatever it is, all you're doing when you use casts like that is to circumvent the type-safety of C++.  The compiler knows something is wrong, but you're claiming you know better by applying such casts.

Comment: @errno_44 in `GetThatRow((Row*)&mySuperRow);` the cast is not necessary since `SuperRow` derives from `Row`, so a `SuperRow*` pointer can be used as-is wherever a `Row*` pointer is expected.  Same with `SuperRow&` and `Row&` references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I can't tell if it is really .. legal.

`GetData` and `GetDataOtherWay` are not "legal". The behaviour of the program is undefined.

`GetRowsOtherWay` by itself is fine although, you should probably use a reference instead of pointer argument. If you do use a pointer, then you should probably check that it isn't null.

> Is this just "not okay" with containers? Because everywhere in our code base I see people casting object ptrs to their base classes, ie `GetThatRow((Row*)&mySuperRow);`

Converting a pointer to a pointer to base is OK. However, vector of derived object is not derived from vector of base object. Vector has no base class at all.

Note that the cast there is superfluous and risky. Conversion to base pointer is implicit, so `GetThatRow(&mySuperRow)` works just as well. If you want to make it explicit, use `static_cast` so that the compiler will enforce type safety.

> This works

Appearance of "working" as you expected is an example of a possible undefined behaviour.

---

> Shouldn't explicitly casting an object to its base class be the same as explicitly casting a vector of objects to a vector of the objects base class?

It is not the same. Also, we are discussing conversion of pointers (although applies of references as well) here, not conversion of objects. There exists a static conversion from a pointer type to another pointer type in the same inheritance hierarchy. There does not exist a static conversion from a pointer to one vector to a pointer to another vector. Those types are not related through inheritance.

> How do we know this is UB?

Because the standard says so (quote from the standard draft):

> [basic.lval]
>
> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through
>   a glvalue whose type is not similar ([conv.qual]) to one of the
>   following types **the behavior is undefined**:
>
> - the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object, or
> - a char, unsigned char, or std::byte type.

`std::vector<Row>` is not similar to the dynamic type of `*rows` (which is `std::vector<SuperRow>`) nor is similar to a signed or unsigned corresponding type, nor is it similar to `char`, `unsigned char` or `std::byte`.

A good rule of thumb: Avoid reinterpret casting, and if you need it, make sure that you know the language rules that are involved, and that you're not violating them. And never ever use C-style cast because it does reinterpret casting whether you intended it or not.

---

How to create a vector of derived objects from a vector of base objects: Firstly, you need a function that creates a derived object from the base. A base object is typically not convertible to its derived types, although it is possible to make it so by adding a converting constructor to the derived type. Once you've written such function, use `std::transform` to apply it to the vector of bases.

Converting a vector of derived to vector of bases is simpler, because the base sub object can simply be copied and returned. This operation is called slicing.

Comment: Shouldn't explicitly casting an object to its base class be the same as explicitly casting a vector of objects to a vector of the objects base class? How do we *know* this is UB?

Comment: @errno_44 no, the two types of casts are not the same thing. Casting a single object to a base type is legal and defined behavior. Casting a container of one type to a container of another type is undefined behavior.